# Unable to login in webserver to my page using asp.net membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, sql-server-2012, asp.net-roles

I have used sqlProvider and asp.net login controls to login to my admin page. I created 4 users in the aspMembershipProvider. I am able to login using the same credentials in the localhost. Now that I have uploaded my website in BigRock domain but there I am not able to login. I have copied the database and all the tables. The users exist in **aspnet_membership** table and **asp_Users table**. But still I  am not able to login. Here is my code what I have tried till now.

**Login.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsPostBack)
            ViewState["LoginErrors"] = 0;
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();



    }
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, true);
            string message = "Welcome "+Login1.UserName + "!!!";
            string url = "Admin/Admin.aspx";
            string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
            script += message;
            script += "');";
            script += "window.location = '";
            script += url;
            script += "'; }";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Redirect", script, true);

            Login1.FailureText = "";

        }
        else
        {
            // Username/password are not valid...
            e.Authenticated = false;


        }
    }
```

**This is  my web configuration file:**

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
         connectionStringName="ConnectionString" applicationName="" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
             passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
      minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Is there anything we need to configure while we upload the site to server. 
**If any further details are required I will provide. I need to find a solution for  this.**

Comment: Have you configured forms authentication in IIS?

Comment: Try to add following section to your web.config (don't forget to do iisreset after changing web.config).
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets.. I have added <authentication mode="Forms"> but havent added <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"/> but still my page will be redirected to Login page whenever I try to enter url with admin.aspx. Unless and until successful login it will not redirect there. I guess its not accepting the Credentials properly. Login error will be displayed.

Comment: Maybe your login page is located not in root? If yes then provide url for it in loginUrl parameter.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets Login is located in root itself..

Comment: Do you get any erros? Or login page reappears again after you enter credentials?

Comment: Also did you update your database connection string after deploying web site?

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets.. I have updated my connectionstring. my other database task like inserting into tables, retrieving from the tables which I have created are working fine.. Only the login function is not working properly since I have done it wid asp.net membership functions. After entering correct username and password I am getting login not successful msg and Login page will be displayed again.

Comment: Maybe you virtual path changed? Please refer to this post regarding applicationName parameter: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets.. I will chk it buddy.. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Asp.net membership provider works together  with an application there is a table name "aspnet_Applications". check if there is a row for your application as same database can be run for multiple application

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets.. Thanks for the help.. Dat link helped alot. Its working now.

Comment: @RajeshKumar.. Yes got it..  Thanks for the help. I jus changed the virtual path/application name in the aspnet_Applications table.. Thank u for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks to @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets and @Rajesh Kumar for helping me out. As they said I jus need to set an application name in aspnet_Applications table. So I jus added the said details and now it working fine.